# An analytic game and Ramsey's theorem

Tags: set-theory, ramsey-theory, determinacy, infinite-games

Let  $$P=\{(l_n, m_n)_{n=1}^t: l_n, m_n,t\in\mathbb{N}, l_1<\ldots <l_t, m_1<\ldots <m_t\}$$ and suppose that $T$ is some subset of $P$. Suppose that $T$ also has the following properties:

$1.$ If $(l_n, m_n)_{n=1}^t \in T$ and $k_1<\ldots <k_t$ are integers such that $m_n\leq k_n$ for each $1\leq n\leq t$, then $(l_n, k_n)_{n=1}^t\in T$.

$2.$ If $(l_n, m_n)_{n=1}^t\in T$ and $1\leq r_1<\ldots <r_s \leq t$, then $(l_{r_n}, m_{r_n})_{n=1}^s\in T$.

Identify strictly increasing sequences of $\mathbb{N}$ with infinite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ by identifying a sequence with its range. Let $[\mathbb{N}]$ denote the set of infinite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ and endow $[\mathbb{N}]$ with the Cantor topology. Let $\mathcal{U}$ denote the set of $(l_n, m_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ such that $(l_n, m_n)_{n=1}^t\in T$ for all $t\in \mathbb{N}$ and let $\mathcal{V}$ denote the set of $(l_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ such that there exists $(m_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ such that $(l_n, m_n)_{n=1}^\infty\in \mathcal{U}$. Then $\mathcal{U}$ is closed in $[\mathbb{N}]\times [\mathbb{N}]$ and $\mathcal{V}$, being a projection of $\mathcal{U}$, is an analytic set.

Let us define two types of games. Both games are between Players $S$ And $I$.

**Game type 1**: Player $S$ chooses a subsequence $s_1$ of $(1,2,\ldots)$. Player $I$ chooses a subsequence $t_1$ of $s_1$ and an integer $l_1$ from the sequence $s_1$. Player $S$ chooses a subsequence $s_2$ of $t_1$ such that the first member of $s_2$ exceeds $l_1$. Player $I$ chooses a subsequence $t_2$ of $s_2$ and a member $l_2$ of the sequence $s_2$. Play continues in this way. The result is a sequence of integers $l_1<l_2<\ldots$, and Player $I$ wins if $(l_n)_{n=1}^\infty\in \mathcal{V}$. **If Player $S$ has a winning strategy in this game, it means Player $S$ can play according to the strategy so that $(l_n)_{n=1}^\infty\in \mathcal{V}$. Therefore there exists $(m_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ such that $(l_n, m_n)_{n=1}^\infty\in \mathcal{U}$ (equivalently, $(l_n, m_n)_{n=1}^t \in T$ for all $t\in \mathbb{N}$). Here, all of the choices $l_1, l_2, \ldots$ are made before any of the choices $m_1, m_2, \ldots$ are made.**

**Game type 2**: Player $S$ chooses a subsequence $s_1$ of $(1,2,\ldots)$. Player $I$ chooses a subsequence $t_1$ of $s_1$ and a member $l_1$ of $s_1$. Player $S$ chooses $m_1\in \mathbb{N}$ and a subsequence $s_2$ of $t_1$ such that the first element of $s_2$ exceeds $l_1$. Player $I$ chooses a subsequence $t_2$ of $s_2$ and a member $l_2$ of $s_2$. Play continues in this way, resulting in $l_1<l_2<\ldots$ and $m_1<m_2<\ldots$. Player $S$ wins if $(l_n, m_n)_{n=1}^\infty \in \mathcal{U}$.

In both games, Player $S$ wins if $(l_n, m_n)_{n=1}^t\in T$ for all $t\in\mathbb{N}$. The differences in the two games is that in the first game, Player $S$ is allowed to choose $(m_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ after all choices $l_1, l_2, \ldots$ are made, and in the second game, Player $S$ is required to choose $m_n$ without knowing future choices.

Since $\mathcal{V}$ is analytic, it is Ramsey. This means that for each infinite subsequence $s_0$ of $(1,2,\ldots)$, there exists a further subsequence $s$ of $s_0$ such that either all subsequences of $s$ lie in $\mathcal{V}$, or none of the subsequences of $s$ lie in $\mathcal{V}$. I believe there is a connection between which of these two alternatives occur and winning strategies in games of the first type above. If I am remembering correctly, for every subsequence $s_0$ of $(1,2,\ldots)$, there exists a subsequence $s$ of $s_0$ such that all subsequences of $s$ lie in $\mathcal{V}$ iff Player $S$ has a winnning strategy in Game 1 above (and this result does not depend on $\mathcal{V}$ being constructed in such a specific way as we have here).

My question is: Under the stronger assumptions on $\mathcal{V}$, it it true that a winning strategy for Player $S$ in the first game implies a winning strategy for Player $S$ in the second game? Equivalently (again assuming my memory of the existing result between games and Ramsey's theorem stated in the previous paragraph is correct) if every subsequence $s_0$ of $(1,2,\ldots)$ has a subsequence $s$ such that every subsequence of $s$ lies in $\mathcal{V}$, does Player $S$ has a winning strategy in Game 2 above?

Comment: What does "analytic" mean, and what does this have to do with Ramsey's theorem?

Comment: I have edited the question to answer these questions. In short, there is a known connection between winning strategies in a two player game and which outcome of the Ramsey dichotomy occurs. My question asks, if the target set of the game has some special form, is it possible to establish such a connection between winning strategies in a slightly different game and which outcome of the Ramsey dichotomy occurs.